# Complex numbers and geometry: where to find it

Tags: complex-analysis

I was looking for a description of how to represent complex conditions (geometrically). However I googled it and I don't find anything. I was looking for a good summary of the equation of circle, an ellipse, etc. 
Does anyone know where can I find it?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481582/equation-of-ellipse-hyperbola-parabola-in-complex-form

Answer (score 0):

As regards conics take a look here: [Equation of ellipse, hyperbola, parabola in complex form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481582/equation-of-ellipse-hyperbola-parabola-in-complex-form)

Moreover, if you have a curve in the complex plane given by the equation $f(x,y)=0$, you can find a complex representation in terms of $z,\bar z$, by letting $x=\frac {z+\bar z}{2}, y=\frac {z-\bar z}{2i}$.

Try with the equation of the line $ax+by=c$. It follows that all lines in $\mathbb C$ can be written as 
$$\alpha z + \bar\alpha \ \bar z + \beta = 0$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb C$, $\beta \in \mathbb R$.